# How to create geocoding service (find polygons that intersect a given point)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, memcached, geocode

### SITUATION

I have a database with `2,000,000` cities. All of them have coordinates of the city center and mostly all - GeoJSON boundaries. I'm trying to implement a geocoding service that would find cities that intersect with a given point using `node.js`, `mongodb`, `redis`, `memcached` (and `golang`, if that is necessary, cause I'm just totally new to it )

### PROBLEM

I know how to work with points (lat and lng) since both `MongoDB` and `Redis` support geoindexes but I've never seen anything about polygons.

I guess MongoDB won't really help cause of its speed (since it work on disks), but any memory database should deal with this problem. The thing is I can't even think of any way to implement it.

I'll be happy if someone point me how to make it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may implement a point-in-polygon algorithm yourself. I've done something similar on https://api.3geonames.org

First do a bounding box to identify candidate polygons, then run a PIP. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon

Answer (score 1):

geo.lua (https://github.com/RedisLabs/geo.lua) works with the requirements you have here but it's not very performant (not sure what has changed since last i checked).